# Python script to get all users from ps -eaf command

Tags: linux, python

I need to get all the users from ps -eaf command and add them to array
I prefer to do it with python.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: @Murphy Well combination of no relevance to the site, no attempt, not asking for answer but rather presenting a specification.

Comment: ps -eaf --no-headers | cut -d" " -f1 -s | uniq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3.6                                                      
import subprocess

result = subprocess.check_output(['ps','-eaf']).decode('utf-8')

users = []

for line in result.splitlines():
    name = line.split()[0]
    if name not in users:
        users.append(name)

print(users)
```

For a more comprehensive answer see [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4760517/8516343)

Although as @jdwolf has posted using shell script might be more appropriate in this case.

Comment: Well python is a fine language. It just has nothing to do with Unix & Linux.